# Flutter error. This happened after I had to upgrade gradle to 8.3 from 7.3

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

[FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_logs'.

> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

```
 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).]

This is the error. I tried installing latest JDK version 21(Didn't uninstall already installed JDK 20).Also tried flutter clean many times. The app also has Firebase Auth in it incase there is a possibility of it being the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I can't pinpoint which is causing the problem either the flutter_logs plugin or the JDK version

you can check the Gradle JDK assigned to your project by running

```
./gradlew --version
```

in android directory or check it in Settings | Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle ( you can see it only by opening the android project within)

to check the compatible JDK use this [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)